# Join Table to QueryFeatureClass

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects

I've joined a table to a SQL-QueryLayer like posted here
[Using IRelQueryTable](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15995/using-irelquerytable)

When I set 
`geoFeatureLayer.FeatureClass = relQueryTable as IFeatureClass;`
the Layer in ArcMap forgot that it is an Query-FeatureClass. So in the Source-Tab of the Layer-Properties-Dialog there is no entry for the DataType and in the Fields-Tab the Fields are listed full-qualified in the Alias-Names. But the Join seems to work because it is correctly listed.
Any idea?

Comment: same issue using shape instead of queryfeatureclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but i get the solution in the esri-developer-forum and don't want to hold it back. 
My mistake was not to use the DisplayFeatureClass of the geofeaturelayer. Also now I use the IDisplayRelationshipClass instead of IRelQueryTable and so it works fine.